# Close a RecordSet in a form but still display the last data it contained (access 2003)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm working on a bit of Access 2003 VBA code that pulls data from a temporary table and shows it in a forms recordset, I then need to delete the temp table but I can't do this until I've disconnected from the Recordset, which removes the data.

What can I call instead of Recordset.Close or RecordSource = "" which would keep the data on the form but close the connection to the table so I can delete it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, I think you can create a disconnected recordset by setting the recordset's ActiveConnection property to Nothing after you've gotten the data that you wanted. Google "disconnected recordset" for more info.

Comment: Note that this solution requires ADO.

Answer (score 0):

Can you Clone the recordset so you have a copy?

Comment: I have done this before. Create a new recordset, copy the field structure and then copy the data over. Basica implement the ADODB.RecordSet.CLONE functionality for a DAO recordset.